Is every compact set in the metric topology closed in the minimal topology containing the closed balls as closed sets?
Let $X$ be a set and $d$ be a metric. I'm interested in the minimal topology $\mathcal{T}$ over $X$ such that every set of the form $\{y\in X:d(y,x)\le r\}$, with $x\in X$ and $r>0$, is closed. In other words, I consider the subbase $\{y\in X:d(y,x)>r\}$, with $x\in X$ and $r>0$. As the comment pointed out, allowing $r=0$ or not does not make a difference since every $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all closed balls centered at $x$.
An easiest example would be: if $d$ is the discrete metric, then the closed balls are either singletons or the whole $X$, so $\mathcal{T}$ is the cofinite topology. Another easy example would be a bounded interval equipped with the usual metric, where $\mathcal{T}$ and the metric topology coincide because the complement of an open ball is always a closed ball of the union of two closed balls. Unfortunately, these are the only examples where I could determine explicitly the topology $\mathcal{T}$.
I do not hope for a complete characterization of this topology (I would glad if it does exist!), but I was wondering if this topology has been studied somewhere. My question is: Is every compact set in the metric topology closed in $\mathcal{T}$? If not, is at least this result correct for $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual metric, so we are interested in the minimal topology containing every bounded closed interval as a closed set?

I don't get why you don't have singletons, metric induce Hausdorff spaces and the intersection of your closed set for $r \to 0$ would thus give you the singleton ${x}$. To me it is the same topology

@julio_es_sui_glace Yes, I forgot it. Thanks for the remark!

If you vote for a close, could you please kindly leave a comment on the details or clarity that should be added?

Since the topology is the same I don't see what remains to be answered?

@julio_es_sui_glace Sorry, but why the topology is the same? I have stated in the question that the minimal topology containing the closed balls wrt a discrete metric (singletons or whole space) is the cofinite topology. Did I make an error on this one?

From my understanding, you definition of the topology is given by every closed ball as your closed set, so this is exactly the definition od the topology given by your original metric

@julio_es_sui_glace But no, as shown by my example. This is because the complement of an open ball is not a closed ball.

Oh yes you are right, however I did not vote to close it

@julio_es_sui_glace Ok, no worries :)

Compacts do remain compact in the new topology; however, the new space is generally not T_2, explaining why they need not be closed immediately.

Given a subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$, let $N_r(A)$ denote the open $r$-neighborhood of $A$ in $X$. Then for every compact $A\subset X$ and $r>0$ there exists a finite subset $\{a_i: i=1,...,n\}\subset A$ such that
$$
A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(a_i,r) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \bar{B}(a_i,r)\subset N_{2r}(A),
$$
where $\bar{B}(a,r)$ is the closed $r$-ball centered at $a$. Of course,
$$
\bigcap_{r} N_{2r}(A)=A.
$$
Hence, every compact (with respect to the original metric topology) subset $A$ is an intersection of finite unions of closed $r$-balls in $(X,d)$. In particular, $A^c\in {\mathcal T}$.

That's nice. Thanks!
